# How to store session through all test using Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

Im currently trying to learn Cypress 10 and I came to an issue where I see that every `it` I do, it clears the cookies which is not what I want and here is my code...

```
Suite('My First Test', () => {
  before(() => {
    prepare();

    cy.visit('https://barrythrill.com');

    cy.get('.start-from-zero').should('be.visible').click();

    ...
  });

  Scenario('My first test cases', () => {
    Given('we are on the webpage');

    When('we save the list', () => {
          // no cy.visit
      ... // we save the list it will automatically login and it creates a cookie called BAR (has a dynamic cookie)
    });

    Then('we are able to open all-list and close it', () => {
      ... // no cy.visit
    });

    When('we remove the list through API', () => {
      ... // no cy.visit
    });
    Then('we should still be logged it', () => {
        ... // cy.visit(''https://barrythrill.com')
            // We should still be logged in through ` When('we save the list', ()`
    });
  });
});
```

I was not able to figure out how I can use cy.session here or to create a correct tests for my test cases. I wonder if anyone here can help me on either how I can improve my code where I can still be logged in through whole test or how I can implement cy.session without needing to call cy.visit for each `it`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume `prepare()` is getting your cookies?

I think what you need to do is add a `beforeEach()` with `cy.session()` and call `prepare()` inside it.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('prepare', () => {
    prepare();
  })
})
```

The session is invoked for every `it()`, but only the first time calls `prepare()` - after that it sets cookies from cache.

You probably still need the `before()` as-is to allow `cy.visit()` to work.

Here I'm starting at the top of Cypress recipe page, and test1 ends up at the Blogs section which is where test2 starts off.

---

#### Preserving location between tests

Not sure this works with cucumber, or if any visit at all mucks up your test flow.

Cypress recommends performing `cy.visit()` straight after `cy.session()` as in the following sample.

You can preserve the last location after each test with a `afterEach()`. The visit in the next `beforeEach()` call will use that location.

```js
Cypress.session.clearAllSavedSessions()

let location = 'https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes'

beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session('cookies', () => {
    cy.setCookie('test', 'my-cookie')
  })
  cy.visit(location)
})

afterEach(() => {
  location = cy.state('window').location.href
})

it('test1', () => {
  expect(cy.state('window').location.href)
    .to.eq('https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes')

  cy.getCookie('test').then(cookie => {
    expect(cookie.value).to.eq('my-cookie')
  })

  // navigate elsewhere
  cy.visit('https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Blogs')
});

it('test2', () => {
  expect(cy.state('window').location.href)
    .to.eq('https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes#Blogs')

  cy.getCookie('test').then(cookie => {
    expect(cookie.value).to.eq('my-cookie')
  })
});
```

Comment: Its the row `When('we save the list', () => {` where it logins the user and then it will automatically create a cookie. so prepare just does some settings such as auth, enabling some features and such. Not logging in.

Comment: Is the code there something you can shift to `beforeEach()`?

Comment: I mean what I could do is that I could do a login before a test... but it feels odd that I need to login then for every `it` I do? - Unless I misunderstood how it works?

Comment: and I also believe if I do the way you recommended, dont I need to do cy.visit for every IT?

Comment: You're not really logging in every `it`, because of the cache effect of `session` the login code inside `session` callback is only ever called once (to prime the cache) thereafter session restores the cookies from cache. You can try it and add a `console.log('login')` inside `session`, it will only print out once.

Comment: I do get the message: We always navigate you here after cy.session()

To continue your test, follow up the command with cy.visit(), meaning that it wont continue without a cy.visit for each `it` - feels odd...

Comment: Actually from previous question `cy.session()` resets location to a blank page - so you will need to visit on each test. A bit of a blunder wrt to that IMO.

Comment: Totally agree.. my problem is that I am not able to do cy.visit for each `it` due to when I click on some button, it redirects to a page with a dynamic URL session (in the url) and that means I cannot pre-know what URL I will get. If that make sense? Maybe you have other suggestions?

Comment: I think you can still use the cookie preserve functions at the moment. I think they will modify `session` (it's still experimental).

Comment: I tried to use the cookie preserve but it seems to be deprecated already in Cypress 10

Comment: Hi, I just saw your updated code. This will unfortunately also fail for me. Atleast for my test cases. I will need to figure out something else. Perhaps I will just end up needing to do a login button where I can call it

Comment: Bad luck - BTW I think cookie preserve requires `experimentalSessionAndOrigin: false`. It seems to be working in v 10.3.0.

Comment: Weird, according to https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Defaults - It says deprecated

Comment: But not removed... You get strike-through in VSCode because of `cypress.d.ts` but the code still works. Just took me a while to realize the `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` needed to be off. Same with `cy.route()`, it stuck around for ages after `cy.intercept()` was live.